# How to remove "...php" from multiple links

Tags: php

Here is my site:
http://www.ezcsgoskins.net/
as you can see the index.php is already removed from my url but how can I do this with every page if you click on support at the left bar you'll see in the URL is support.html

Comment: Please see https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: your favourite search engine would've provided you kajillions of resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.htaccess` to have clean URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Obviously if you have `*.html` pages you will need to change them to `.php` or create another `RewriteRule` for it.

Source from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?278057-RESOLVED-removing-php-ext-from-URL-with-htaccess)

Comment: Still doesnt work. look at this link http://www.ezcsgoskins.net/contact.php

Comment: Remove  # from the RewriteEngine on

Comment: Still doesn't work. The href to the page is just contact.php is that good?

Comment: You need to change it to contact instead.

Comment: I just tried it and it works http://www.ezcsgoskins.net/contact

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

source http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Remember remove extensions from a tags href like.

```
<a href="/support">support</a>
```